# Solutions of polynomials in non integral domains of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

If we consider a polynomial of degree $d$ and $p$ a prime number. Let $a\ge 1$ an integer such that $a\ge d$.

We try to estimate the number of roots of the polynomial $\pmod{p^a}$.

We know that for $a=1$ we have a field so the number of roots is at most $d$.

For $a>1$ it seems to have the same numbers of roots as $a=1$ but I'm not sure (I took $(x-1)(x-2)\equiv 0 \pmod{27}\ $ we have two roots, the degree is $2$ but $a=3$).

I don't know if it works with the powers of $2$ (we necessary have roots with multiplicity in that case)...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Generically", the number of solutions (mod $p^a$) will be the same as the number of solutions (mod $p$). (There are exceptions though.)

Without knowing it, you are looking for the magic of [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)!

Comment: OK nice,  so the numbers of solutions is the same as $\pmod p$. Is there a link with the Hensel's lifting method ?

Comment: I think the link I put in the answer is a good start

Comment: Ok I find an article http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull47/R4701.pdf which seems to talk a little about what I was asking. Thanks for the answer ! My question is useful to generalize a Lagrange's theorem.